# IPython Notebook 101, how to draw scatter charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, jupyter-notebook

101 question --
How to draw scatter charts in IPython Notebook?

I'm not a Python programmer but I want to draw scatter charts by following some exiting examples, but I didn't find any. As the result, my [IPython Notebook scatter charts drawing is failing](https://gist.github.com/suntong/1027fb044f35b17be671). I.e., I didn't see any scatter charts drawn. In comparison, my [IPython Notebook `pylab.plot` drawing is working fine](https://gist.github.com/suntong/5d9b6556e0b409ef3b32). I.e., I can see my charts drawn.

I've also tried to add `pylab.show()` at the end but that doesn't help.

Please help.

Comment: I found some examples here: https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/

Comment: start your notebook with `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: Look at 
http://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/~robitaille/PY4SCI_SS_2014/_static/11.%20Introduction%20to%20Matplotlib.html, why he can draw that scatter charts inline while I can't?
I've just updated my https://gist.github.com/suntong/1027fb044f35b17be671, please take a look.

Comment: @cel, I got it working (my gist updated). Don't know it is `%pylab inline` or `%matplotlib inline` though, but I'll accept yours as answer if you do it. Thanks

Comment: Don't use `%pylab` - it pollutes your namespace by importing everything from numpy and pylab. Use `%matplotlib` instead.